# How to generate jar for maven parent project

Tags: maven, parent, pom.xml

Maven requires a parent project to have

`<packaging>pom</packaging>`

clause in the parent's pom.xml. When such a project installed, only a pom-file generated into the maven repository. Jar-file is not generated, no matter if the parent project has any Java code. That forces me to have extra empty parent projects, which is overkill. Logically, some of my libraries could be parents at the same time.

Is there a way to generate both pom and jar files for a parent project without removing/adding the `packaging` clause between installs?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use Maven Jar Plugin and Maven Build Helper. Example POM:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>test</groupId>
  <artifactId>test</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version>

  <packaging>pom</packaging>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.7</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>attach-artifacts</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>attach-artifact</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <artifacts>
                <artifact>
                  <file>test-${project.version}</file>
                  <type>jar</type>
                </artifact>
              </artifacts>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>jar</goal>
            </goals>
            <phase>package</phase>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

Maven build results:

```
mvn install
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building test 1.0
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- build-helper-maven-plugin:1.7:attach-artifact (attach-artifacts) @ test ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:2.4:jar (default) @ test ---
[WARNING] JAR will be empty - no content was marked for inclusion!
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.3.1:install (default-install) @ test ---
[INFO] Installing /home/username/projects/test/pom.xml to /home/username/.m2/repository/test/test/1.0/test-1.0.pom
[INFO] Installing /home/username/projects/test/test-1.0 to /home/username/.m2/repository/test/test/1.0/test-1.0.jar
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.805s
[INFO] Finished at: Thu Sep 06 13:33:20 EDT 2012
[INFO] Final Memory: 4M/119M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

A note on Maven practices:

Parent modules are typically where you define the dependencies and plugins used in common by all your child modules. It rarely has output of its own.  You probably want to have a "distribution" sub-module that aggregates all your other module artifacts, rather than attempting to do it in the parent module.

Comment: Thank you, noahz, for your solution. I want to generate jar-file for a parent project to avoid extra empty projects in my Eclipse Workspace and thus to simplify project relations. I'm new to maven, so I might be wrong. Do you recommend to use empty parent projects? I suspect your solution will conflict children projects, which have own jar-building plugins.

Comment: It is perfectly fine to have a parent project which is "empty" (generates no artifacts) in that it only serves to define property settings, dependency versions, plugins, etc. used by child projects.  BTW - if you use my solution, please accept the answer by clicking the checkmark.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer and the explanations. I'm going to follow your recommendation to use empty projects as parents.

Comment: This helped me get my project built, but then it couldn't find the main class. When I remove the module and then build, it finds the main class no problem when I go to run it. But when it has the module linked and the above plugins configured, it builds successfully but can't find the main.

Comment: @Trevor I suggest you open a new StackOverflow question referencing this one but focusing on your specific problem